# Would you ever want an action method to not return an ActionResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC the [convention](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-03-cs.aspx) is that a controller action method should return an `ActionResult` (or a type derived from `ActionResult`).

However, you can write a public method that returns pretty much anything and if that method is called (from a browser) the framework will package the return value up as a `ContentResult` and the browser receives a page of plain text.

This is all very interesting - but would you ever want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not returning anything from an action method is essentially not responding to the client's HTTP request with a response.

An empty request might make sense in some cases (HTTP status being enough of a reply), but all web application patterns return something more than this (including, if I understand it correctly, REST: the new state of the entity).

Answer (score 2):

When you want to render something directly from your controller? e.g. using Response.Write(...); (or using other Response methods).